# What type of AI model should I use to generate practice questions?

Tags: ai-design, generative-model, language-model

I have a set of multiple choice English questions, and I wanted to use AI to generate more questions to quiz myself with. I know there are platforms online to accomplish this, but I wanted to challenge myself to create my own simple AI architecture. After training it on some English questions, I want it to be able to generate new questions to help me study.

Which ML/intelligence model(s) should I use as a baseline?